# How to verify multiple emails and get the emails data?

Tags: java, sql

Suppose my table is like this:

```
table user
id | email | password | age | gender
1 | yao@a.com | password | 1 | m
2 | yao@c.com | password | 2 | m
```

Assuming as a regular user, I know nothing about the table and its data. In a form, I enter the following emails to get their id number:

```
(yao@a.com, yao@b.com, yao@c.com)
```

So the query would be:

```
select id from user where email in (yao@a.com, yao@b.com, yao@c.com)
```

should return:

```
(1,2)
```

Now, how do I figure out which id is for which user? I was thinking of querying one user at a time but if the list becomes too big, it would be bad practice.

What is a better method to implement something like this?

The reason I need to know which id belong to which user is because frontend needs to tell the user which emails didnt work etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select email,id from user where email in ('yao@a.com', 'yao@b.com', 'yao@c.com')` will return both the email and the id (matched up).